# Iterating over a JSON array in scala

Tags: json, scala, specs

I'm using the JSON lib net.sf.json(http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/package-summary.html) in my scala code.
Also, I'm using the specs BDD framework (http://code.google.com/p/specs/) for unit testing. In the doBefore block, i have the following code:

```
doBefore {
  iter = serversJSON.iterator()
}
```

serversJSON is a JSONArray object. Outside the doBefore block, I have declared the variables used as follows

```
var serversJSON:JSONArray = null
var iter:Iterator[JSONArray] = null
```

But on compilation I'm getting the following error.

> error: type mismatch; found   :
>   java.util.Iterator[?0] where type ?0
>   required:
>   java.util.Iterator[net.sf.json.JSONArray]
>   iter = serversJSON.iterator()

I guess the way i have declared the iter object outside doBefore is incorrect. How to fix this?

Please Help
Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated [here](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html#iterator%28%29), the JSON library's `iterator` method returns a raw `Iterator`, not an `Iterator[JSONArray]`. You'll want to declare it as follows:

```
var serversJSON:JSONArray = null
var iter:Iterator[_] = null
```